# Looking for ergonomic Windows shortcut utility

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, ergonomics, navigation

A few years ago I found and installed a small Windows utility that enabled me to navigate by using keystrokes instead of the mouse. It ran in the background, and with a keyboard shortcut it brought up a command prompt with a translucent background in which you could type a URL, a disk location or other resource types. After pressing Enter, it would open that resource in the relevant application.

Some time later, the team that developed this utility joined Mozilla to work on some ergonomic stuff there and they stopped developing the application ;) I can't remember if it was open-sourced or not.

I can't find the name of the utility anywhere. I have tried lots of googling but nothing came up. I believe the app was originally written in Python for what it's worth.

Please help!!

Comment: Is it something like Launchy (http://www.launchy.net) or SlickRun (http://bayden.com/SlickRun/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[enzo](http://www.humanized.com/)

Comment: Sounds like this is it, but I'll wait for Shimon to confirm :)

Comment: Bingo! Humanoid's Enso Launcher it was. Thank you! I'm glad to see they still have the download on their site.

EDIT: Sorry I can't upvote you. I'm new to the site.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows run box can automatically open many things, press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to quickly get the box up, type in what you're after.

URL's and disk locations are automatically opened in a browser / explorer as required (I tested this on Windows XP moments ago).

Disk locations also auto-fill (eg, typing `c:\program files\a` should show a drop down of all folders starting with `a` inside your program files for easy selection). So do URL's, but they probably rely on your Internet Explorer history (ie, no so good if you use another browser).

I imagine many "other resource types" should be as well, because the run box just triggers the default action for the file/resource/etc - it has the same effect as double-clicking on the target.

Comment: Useful, but not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for THAT program.